# Cudamat Error: Cannot open shared object file

Tags: python, python-2.7, cudamat

I have been trying to install cudamat on a Ubuntu 18.04 machine. Cuda toolkit has been installed (with a work-around, surprisingly NVIDIA hasn't provided support yet.) But now when I try importing cudamat, the following error pops up,

> OSError: cudamat/libcudamat.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Possible work-around for this has to be setting the correct path? That is were I am stuck at the moment. I am running a python 2.7 version but I also have python3 with the anaconda install, has this in someway messed up my path. Because when I run the PATH command from the setup.py file for cudamat I get the following PATH

```
 print(os.environ.get('PATH'))
```

> /usr/local/cuda-9.2/bin:/home/rahul/**anaconda3**/bin:/home/rahul/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin

If there is a fix, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Edit1: I believe the error might also be due to CUDA path and not CUDAmat? I would like to know if this is a valid claim.

Answer (score 0):

[cudamat](https://github.com/cudamat/cudamat) contains library functions written in CUDA C and expose them through python via it's C interface(python's interpreter is implemented in C). So they compile the CUDA C code into a shared library which is `libcudamat.so`. The solution might be trying to install from [source](https://github.com/cudamat/cudamat). The instruction in their repo works fine.

> Edit1: I believe the error might also be due to CUDA path and not CUDAmat? I would like to know if this is a valid claim.

Not necessarily, check your installation again. I would recommend installing from source.

Comment: Thank you. I was on a tight schedule and I migrated to windows to get it up and running. It would be great if someone else can verify this and I can mark it as resolved?

Comment: How did you install cudamat?

Comment: I followed instructions from the official repository, ran the setup.py file.

Comment: can you locate `libcudamat.so`?